# How to revert back composer update?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Today I ran `composer update` and the update broke my site completely. I found in the php.log the following information:

> 72.15.153.139 - - [11/Nov/2015:21:01:45 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"
>   [Wed Nov 11 21:01:48 2015] [error] [client 127.7.179.129] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or \\ (T_NS_SEPARATOR) in /var/lib/openshift/55c481747628e14556000188/app-root/runtime/repo/config/vendor/danielstjules/stringy/tests/CreateTest.php on line 5
>   72.15.153.139 - - [11/Nov/2015:21:01:48 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"

Seems that "danielstjules/stringy" is the one to blame. But how can I revert back to an older version (or using a news version?) of this package? I tried to modify composer.lock file, and changed

```
            "require": {
            "danielstjules/stringy": "~1.8",
```

to

```
        "require": {
            "danielstjules/stringy": "~1.9",
```

and run `composer update` again, but it gave the information:

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Nothing to install or update
>   Writing lock file
>   Generating autoload files
>   PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or \ (T_NS_SEPARATOR) in /var/lib/openshift/55c481747628e14556000188/app-root/runtime/repo/config/vendor/danielstjules/stringy/tests/CreateTest.php on line 5
>   Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error
>
> [RuntimeException]
>     Error Output: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNC
>     TION), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or \ (T_NS_SEPARATOR) in /var/lib/o
>     penshift/55c481747628e14556000188/app-root/runtime/repo/config/vendor/danie
>     lstjules/stringy/tests/CreateTest.php on line 5

How can I rollback this package? Thanks.

EDIT 2:

`composer install` will modify `composer.lock` automatically. I modified `composer.json` instead, and it fetched the old version 1.8 successfully.

But the build still failed. [This issue description](https://github.com/danielstjules/Stringy/issues/85) had the reason. But after I `rm -rf test/`, the problem was still there.

EDIT 3:

I tried the following:

1. `rm -rf vendor/`
2. `composer update`

The problem was gone.

Comment: Do you commit your `composer.lock` file?

Comment: Your `composer.lock` should be in version control. That'd allow you to just revert the changes to it, then do `composer install` to reinstall the known functional versions.

Comment: First, you should specify what exactly version you want update to. Modify `composer.lock` without using `~` character. If still broken, we have to using GIT or SVN to revert back to previous revision absolutely.

Comment: @VũTuấnAnh You should not modify `composer.lock` in any way. If you don't trust Composer to create a (according to version requirements) valid set of software packages, who should be able to do this? If there are versions that you want to avoid, modify `composer.json` to explicitly exclude them, then run `update` again. Or roll back to the previous set of versions.

Comment: @Sven You are right. I this case, i should modify `composer.json` instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you check the [composer version specification documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md), the `~` operator gets the latest version that is backwards-compatible according the principles of [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/). That means that `~1.8` is equivalent to `>=1.8 <2.0.0` and likewise `~1.9` is the same as `>=1.9 <2.0.0`. In other words, `~1.8` will return the SAME THING as `~1.9` if the latest version is `>=1.9`. If you really want to use version `1.8`, just do this:

```
"danielstjules/stringy": "1.8",
```

That will get EXACTLY version `1.8`. Of course you'll need to run `composer update` afterwards.

I find the composer versioning syntax tricky to remember myself.

Answer (score 180):

How to revert an update? Easy: Restore the `composer.lock` file from your version control system that was used before you updated.

The `composer.lock` exactly records which software was installed. So it is paramount to commit this file into version control in order to be able to go back to a working version in case of update failure.

Running `composer install` will always install the software versions recorded in `composer.lock`, it will only act like `update` if this file is not present.

Comment: Just revert the files and run `composer install`. Worked!